# Django Development Server Question

Tags: python, django

I noticed that when I am developing a Django App in debug mode, I sometimes see this output on my server stdout:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/josephmisiti/projects/temp/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 284, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/Users/josephmisiti/projects/temp/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 324, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "/Users/josephmisiti/projects/temp/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 403, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "/Users/josephmisiti/projects/temp/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 467, in send_headers
    self.send_preamble()
  File "/Users/josephmisiti//projects/temp/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 385, in send_preamble
    'Date: %s\r\n' % http_date()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 297, in write
    self.flush()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 284, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(buffer)
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
[27/Aug/2011 11:54:14] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 2
```

Can someone tell me why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browser closed the socket connection before the server could finish sending the response (e.g. you closed the tab before it loaded all the way).  Don't worry about it.